# Column order when selecting column_names in Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I want display a table content along with column names.

I have used SQL query for columns

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = $mytable"
```

and I have used SQL query for content

```
"SELECT * FROM $mytable"
```

Both are working fine. Only thing is that, order of columns is different. Some times its just reverse. sometimes it is reverse with some shift of 2-3 columns depending on number of column in $mytable.

Comment: I provided an answer, but I'm not sure why you are taking this approach to query column names separate from the data query?

Comment: Can you use USER_TAB_COLUMNS instead of ALL_TAB_COLUMNS. If there are more than one table in different schemas with the same name and if your user has grants on those tables then you will get column names pertaining to both those tables from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS. If you don't want to use USER_TAB_COLUMNS then add OWNER = <user_name> condition to your query. To solve your problem add ORDER BY COLUMN_ID as Wolf has suggested.

Answer (score 6):

You need to include an order by when you query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` on `COLUMN_ID`:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = $mytable ORDER BY COLUMN_ID".
```

This orders the columns by the order created.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better approach is to simply read the column names from the returned resultset. This means you need only one query:

```
$conn = oci_connect($username, $password, $connectionString);
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, 'select * from mytable');
oci_execute($stmt);

$headers = false;
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    if (!$headers) {
        // this will only output the headers on the first iteration.
        print_r(array_keys($row));
        $headers = true;
    }
    print_r($row);
}
```

Or you could use [`oci_field_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-field-name.php) against the resultset but I've always felt the above method is simpler.

---

***Edit:*** In case there are no results, you won't be able to get the keys (since the array is empty). You can add the following code after the `while` loop to handle that:

```
if (!$headers) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= oci_num_fields($stmt); $i++) {
        echo oci_field_name($stmt, $i), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```